# Data Type Haskell error

Tags: haskell-platform, template-haskell, haskell

I declare some data type as follow:

```
data TX_OR_TY = TX | TY
data TX = X Int
data TY = Y Float
```

Now I write some function return their data type:

```
funcTX :: TX
funcTX = X 3

funcTY :: TY
funcTY = Y 5

ordFuncTX :: TX -> Int -> Bool
ordFuncTX (X a) b = (a > b)

funcTX_TY :: TX_OR_TY
funcTX_TY = if (ordFuncTX funcTX 4) then funcTX else funcTY
```

Function funcTX_TY will return a type of TX_OR_TY by comparing the value of TX with 4, if bigger then return TX, if smaller then return TY. But when compiling, it announces that it couldn't match expected type **TX_OR_TY** with **TX**. How can I fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data declarations are probably not what you intended.

TX_OR_TY just defines two *constructors*: TX and TY.

The following data declarations define the *types* TX and TY.

You probably meant something like

```
data TX_OR_TY = AnX TX | AnY TY
data TX = X Int
data TY = Y Float
-- Now I write some function return their data type:

funcTX :: TX
funcTX = X 3

funcTY :: TY
funcTY = Y 5

ordFuncTX :: TX -> Int -> Bool
ordFuncTX (X a) b = (a > b)

funcTX_TY :: TX_OR_TY
funcTX_TY = if (ordFuncTX funcTX 4) then AnX funcTX else AnX funcTY
```

Note that TX_OR_TY is a specialized version of the [Either](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aEither) data type from the standard prelude. To use Either, omit the definition of TX_OR_TY and change the function thus:

```
funcTX_TY :: Either TX TY
funcTX_TY = if (ordFuncTX funcTX 4) then Left funcTX else Right funcTY
```

Comment: If I declare like data TX_OR_TY = X Int | Y Float. It will be ok. But sometime TX and TY I would like to declare them separately in case TX and TY is a really complex type, and I don't want to declare in one line

Comment: @chipbk10 declaring them separately is ok, and my example still uses your definitions of the TX and TY types.

Comment: data TX_OR_TY = TX TX | TY TY  ---> what does this mean? It makes me more confused.

Comment: I've renamed the type constructors in my example. Less confusing now?